# How to make  grep display only the matching regexp?

Tags: grep, regex

I am trying to find data from files using grep, but grep usually prints out the filename as well as the line where the term is found.

In this case, I am looking for a special regexp and I want grep to print all items matching the regexp, not the line or the filename. In other words, I want to see only the matched regular expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, that's the `-o` option possibly combined with `-h` to suppress the filename.